# Using different projection for each entity subtype

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Is it possible define diferent Projections by SubTypes and Spring Data REST 
use the most concrete projection about class type?

This issue was exposed on JIRA issue [DATAREST-739](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-739) and also exists a merge commit but this not appears on official [changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/src/main/resources/changelog.txt) and also I don't found any documentation or guide to solved it with the current releases.

The use case sample used into the issue is:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
public abstract class Message implements Identifiable<UUID> { ... }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TEXT")
@JsonTypeName("TEXT")
public class TextMessage extends Message { ... }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TODO")
@JsonTypeName("TODO")
public class TodoMessage extends Message { Boolean isDone; }

@Projection(name = "summary", types = TodoMessage.class)
public class TodoMessageSummary { Boolean getIsDone(); }

@Projection(name = "summary", types = TextMessage.class)
public class TextMessageSummary { ... }

public interface MessageRepo extends JpaRepository<Message, UUID> { ... }

@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = TodoMessageSummary.class)
public interface TodoMessageRepo extends JpaRepository<Message, UUID> { ... }

@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = TextMessageSummary.class)
public interface TextMessageRepo extends JpaRepository<TextMessage, UUID> { ... }
```

*First issue: how to define an excerpt projection for MessageRepo to use TodoMessageSummary for TodoMessage entities and TextMessageSummary for TextMessage?*

*Second issue: how to define projection for another entity that has a Message field? Let's say you have the following:*

```
@Projection(name = "summary", types = Dashboard.class)
public class DashboardSummary {
  List<Message> getMessages();
}
```

**SOLVED:**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is use inheritance into the subtype projections:

```
@Projection(name = "summary", types = Message.class)
public class MessageSummary { 
    @Value("#{target.getClass().getSimpleName()}")
    String getType();    
}

@Projection(name = "summary", types = TextMessage.class)
public class TextMessageSummary extends MessageSummary { ... }

@Projection(name = "summary", types = TodoMessage.class)
public class TodoMessageSummary extends MessageSummary {
     Boolean getIsDone();
}
```

The Spring REST `@RepositoryRestResource` returns an array of Messages using the concrete subtype projection ( isDone must be appear into TodoMessage instances)

This issue a bit more complex if you need to made the same into a extendend `@RequestMapping` into a `Controller`, to do so I use the next snnipeed:

```
    Page<Message> results = repository.findAll(predicate, pageable);
    Converter<? super Message, ? extends MessageSummary> converter= l -> {
        if(l instanceof TextMessage){
            return projectionFactory.createProjection(TextMessageSummary.class,l);
        }
        else if(l instanceof TodoMessage){
            return projectionFactory.createProjection(TodoMessageSummary.class,l);
        }
        else { 
            return projectionFactory.createProjection(MessageSummary.class,l);
        }
    };
    Page<MessageSummary> projected =results.map(converter);
    return pagedAssembler.toResource(projected);
```

Note that if only need *resource type info* on frontend for read only purpose (i.e. for POST/PUT use concrete subtype endpoints) I think that is not really needed use the *@JsonTypeInfo* because using SpEL into projections allow get this type info more easy and flexible:

```
@Value("#{target.getClass().getSimpleName()}")
String getType();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. We have such sub-types structure in our application.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
public abstract class Vehicle {
  protected VehicleType type;
}

public class Plane extends Vehicle {
  private String title;
}
```

Projections for them:

```
public interface VehicleProjection {
  String getType();
}

@Projection(name = "default", types = Plane.class)
public interface PlaneProjection extends VehicleProjection {
  String getTitle();
}
```

And rest repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "collectionName", path = "path",
        excerptProjection = VehicleProjection.class)
public interface RestVehicleRepository<T extends Vehicle> extends MongoRepository<T, String> {

}
```

Also we've registered those projections in configuration. Not sure whether it is required for your case, because we have more then one projection for each sub-type:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRestConfigurerAdapter extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
 @Override
        public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(final RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
          config.getProjectionConfiguration().addProjection(PlaneProjection.class,
                    "default", Plane.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my trouble was that I need the subtype projections on a controller custom mapping. I finally solved it and during the process It let me get knowledge over other useful issues